# Does isometry preserve volume on open sets?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, manifolds

Suppose there are two open sets $A,B$. $h$ is an isometry. And the function $h$ maps $A$ to $B$; $h(A)=B$. I need to show that isometry is volume preserving.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the relationship between $f,g$?

Comment: Oh sorry I fixes it. Sorry again

Comment: Is $h$ an isometry? What is the containing space. You are a little light on detail...

Comment: The problem was to find out whether the isometry is volume reserving. My idea was that if I take a function f that is cts such that it has the same integral over them, then I would prove it. It was my idea

Comment: What if $f(a)=1$ for each $a\in A$ and $f(b)=b$ for each $b\in B$?...The condition that $h$ is continuous and integrable is not enough. Also you haven't answered the questions of @copper.hat yet.

Comment: @copper.hat h is an isometry. I do not know what containing space is tho :)

Comment: Take $h(x) = x+1$, $A=(0,1), B=(1,2)$ and $f(x) = x$, then $\int_A f = {1 \over 2}, \int_B f = {3 \over 2}$.

Comment: Note that isometry has little to do with volume (or measure): you can have metric spaces without defining measures on them and vice verse, spaces with measure without defining metric on them.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I half agree, but note that metric spaces can be endowed with various [Hausdorff measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure).